# is asp.net C# server app rendering into a linux web client ok ? (totally newbie question)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, mono

I am wondering if aspx generated webpage content can be read on linux platforms. Is it **necessary** to have the Mono platform installed on the linux web-clients side ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET generates HTML markup and JavaScript that can be used on **ANY** platform.

Only the server-side requires either Microsoft's .NET (Windows) or Mono (Linux).

Answer (score 5):

Mono is only necessary if you want to host your web server on linux. If you want to see a website you only need a browser.

After if you have a moonlight website, you need the moonlight client.

Answer (score 1):

Not a problem at all, .NET is used to generate standard HTML which is what a web browser understands. There is no need for a .NET implementation on the client.

Answer (score 1):

completely browser dependent. You do not anything else to view a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Well. It depends. Pages can look like crap if you haven't followed the HTML(/xhtml) standard.
This is the case if you havent looked at the HTML specification but only developed using internet explorer.

The second issue is fonts. Are you using Microsoft specific fonts in your HTML/stylesheets?

Other than that, pages should look quite similar in different operating systems / browsers.